# Failed to combine clipping-stencil and RTT?

Tags: three.js, render-to-texture, stencil-buffer

I am trying to render the three.js official demo clipping-stencil to texture,but the result is not right,once I render it to texture,the stencil test is as if not enabled.As the following figure shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A79PD.png)
this is the right result,directly render to screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6Of.png)
this is render to texture,then render to screen,it is not right

I want get right RTT result